How to repair a "pull" shut-off valve for the toilet?
I have one of the shut off valves connected to my toilet where you pull it to stop the water.  The thing is when I pull it to stop the water, it still drips once every 10-12 seconds.  When I push it so water flows thru so I can flush, it drips every 5-6 seconds.
I can't find anything looking like this at Home Depot or Lowes so it might be one of those special parts that they only sell to contractors.  Before I go call a plumber, what can I do to repair this?  Could I take the valve apart to fix it or this is one of those things where it's not worth taking apart to repair and I need to call a plumber to replace the valve?
I've attached a photo to show where the water is dripping from.  I think it's dripping where the green circle is at the metal part.  It doesn't appear to be running down the hose and I felt where the hose meets the tank and that isn't wet either so I'm focusing on the shut off valve.


With a "lock- out" "tag-out"

I would replace it with a modern angle valve and be done with it because getting the parts for that old one is probably close to impossible and its not worth the time

The valve and hose are cheap junk used by the house builder.  Do not attempt to repair it, it's a waste of your time.  If you own this, replacing it with something better is a great investment.
Replacing these with better ones is probably the second most popular genre on youtube after Taylor Swift.  It's not hard, and if you use a quarter-turn Sharkbite shutoff valve and a decent metal braided hose, it's an easy DIY Project.  I think in fact you can buy a Sharkbite toilet kit.
Watch many videos to learn about and anticipate the problems you may face. This one shows you how to miminize damage to the very short bit of pipe you have to work with.

That hose is failing.
There is no viable "repair", only replacement.
These hoses usually have a suggested replacement schedule and that one looks like it's on borrowed time.
Shop for a "toilet supply line with valve" and watch some tutorials. If you are not comfortable with such a task then hire a plumber and pay $150-$200.

So I called a plumber.  Apparently it was the right call.  Looks like they had to use a hacksaw to saw down the length of the valve to get it off the pipe.  Even then, the plumber had to cut off part of the copper pipe to finish the job.  Not sure why he didn't try sanding/smoothing it down but I guess this is why he's the professional and I'm the layperson.
